# Xamarin: Unsure what to cast using DriveFile.Open

Tags: android, xamarin, google-drive-api

I tried to lookup the documentation about DriveFile.Open for Xamarin but still can't find the class to cast the return statement from the code below

```
var pendingResult = driveFile.Open(.. , .., ..) 
var obj = pendingResult.await();
```

On Android Documentation, the class to be casting to is

```
DriveContents driveContents = driveContentsResult.getDriveContents();
```

But i can't find the Class called DriveContentsResult.

Answer (score 1):

#### Non-Async way (using `OnResult` callback)

```
driveFile.Open(_googleApiClient, DriveFile.ModeReadOnly, null).SetResultCallback(this);
```

Will call `onResult` and there you can cast the result:

```
void IResultCallback.OnResult(Java.Lang.Object result)
{
    var contentResults = (result).JavaCast<IDriveApiDriveContentsResult>();
    var driveContent = contentResults.DriveContents;
    D.WriteLine(driveContent.DriveId);

}
```

#### Async way:

```
var driveContentResult = driveFile.OpenAsync(_googleApiClient, DriveFile.ModeReadOnly, null).ContinueWith((resultTask) =>
{
    var driveContentResults = resultTask.Result;
    var driveContent = driveContentResults.DriveContents;
    D.WriteLine(driveContent.DriveId);
});
```

Comment: You are Master, the driveContent now have something on it. Thank you. Where can I find more information about this stuff in Xamarin website.

Comment: I'm not sure if there are any really in-depth guide in C# for Google Drive... :-/ As far how I learn how to do `(result).JavaCast<IDriveApiDriveContentsResult>()` I went through the Async extensions that Xamarin added https://github.com/xamarin/GooglePlayServicesComponents/blob/8770ef489bba315643b2b9513cc91674c1565a97/drive/source/Additions/IPendingResultExtensions.cs

Answer (score 0):

You should probably make your own DrivecontentsResult and implement IDriveApiDriveContentsResult interface and use that concrete class. It is available in Android.Gms.Drive.IDriveApiDriveContentsResult