# There is no open() method for my DriveFile object

Tags: xamarin

I'm very frustrated at this point due to the lack of documentation of the Google Drive API and I'm using Xamarin which makes things worse. I've installed the `Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Drive` package and it's working properly. So fast forward to my problem, I query for files and can successfully get their `DriveID`.

So my code is:

```
DriveFile file = DriveId.AsDriveFile();
//And here I want to use the method file.Open(...);
```

The only methods the `DriveFile` object has available to it is the default `Object` methods e.g. `ToString()`, `Equals()`, `GetType()` and `GetHashCode()`. Am I doing something wrong, why can't I access this method since others have no problem accessing it.

Google says I must use it: https://developers.google.com/drive/android/files

This guy using Xamarin has no problem using the method: [Xamarin: Unsure what to cast using DriveFile.Open](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37498198/xamarin-unsure-what-to-cast-using-drivefile-open)

Any help will be appreciated. I also have access to the MetaData of the files if that helps (to download it using another method)

Comment: The drive library is just going to help you access the files stored on drive. I doubt that its going to have an open method.   You are probably going to have to use the metadata to download it then code your own open method.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply @DalmTo. Well, according to the documentation there should be an Open method in the API (first link). The only reason it wouldn't be there is if the Xamarin library didn't bind that method (which I would accept if I didn't come across the second link). To be clear, the open method doesn't open a file stream but rather according to the documentation "retrieves the locally synced file resource and opens it. If the file is not synced with the local storage, it retrieves the file from the Drive service and returns a DriveContents resource" which the app then reads

Comment: your first link is android not Xamarin.  I wont clam to have done a lot with Xamarin but to my recollection that's two different things.   the Xamarin  library I used is basically the .Net client library.   May be better to wait for someone with more Xamarin knowledge.  Kind of interesting that you can use the android library as well might have to play with that.

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to Xamarin, so please don't accept my word for it but as far as I understand a lot of Android libraries are mapped function for function (with only the naming differing slightly to adhere to C# conventions). A lot of the functions for this library I got from the android documentation where the casing only differed. Some other methods that they used weren't available because they're deprecated but this seems very odd to me because the whole class doesn't have any methods and although one case of someone using that class might not be enough to know for sure, it's all I could get

Comment: @DalmTo I found the solution. It was just a confusing naming of the files. I'll detail the solution below. Thanks for your time anyway :)

Comment: great now I can play with it :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found the solution to my problem. It was a confusing name of the classes. `DriveFile` is the name of the enum-like class of the types of operations. The `IDriveFile` interface is the actual interface that contains the Open method. So when I stored the value as a `var` it worked, I can now get the Open method.

```
var file = onlineFiles[i].DriveId.AsDriveFile();
file.Open(_googleApiClient, DriveFile.ModeReadOnly, null).SetResultCallback(this);
```